# This javascript code doesn't works in IE.This is in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
function changeval(){
var pr =document.getElementById('search').value;
//alert(pr);
if (pr==""){
document.getElementById('searchres').innerHTML="";

document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML ="&nbsp;Search result will show here!<br/>";

}
}
```

This is code in googlemaps.
The above code doesn't works in windows IE.

Comment: Please define "doesn't works".

Comment: Use a framework. I recommend Ender.js or MooTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use temporal variables and insert a `debugger;` statement to see if your code can 'see' the objects you're trying to access, if exists.